# Join multiple tables with ?optional? conditions and get all results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

Using SQL 2008 R2

I am having trouble accomplishing a table join. I think I am just missing something simple. I need to join three tables (CMS, DB, Backups) and get a full list of all the overlaps as well as missing items. Unfortunately, two of the tables don't have simple conditions to do the join on.

Conditions:
1: Every table could have a row that matches no other table
2: Backups Joins on Server_Name and also Backups.Save_Set is like DB.Instance_Name or Backups.Save_Set is like 'ALL'
3: CMS Joins on Server_Name and also CMS.Name is like DB.Name

As you can see from the results of my query below, I am close, but not quite there. I can't seem to get the two top rows or my results to join correctly because they don't match the conditions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't seem to find what I am missing.

create/populate script at bottom

Table: DB

```
ID    Server_Name      Instance_Name        Name        Company_Code
----- ---------------- -------------------- ----------- --------------------
1     Server11         MSSQLSERVER          PUB         14
2     Server11         MSSQLSERVER          Test        10
3     Server11         MSSQLSERVER          fasys       14
4     Server12         MSSQLSERVER          PROD        14
5     Server21         MSSQLSERVER          PROD        24
```

Table: CMS

```
ID          Name                     Server_Name          Responsible
----------- ------------------------ -------------------- ---------------
1           Site1 SQL DB PUB         Server11             PDM
2           Site1 SQL DB Test        Server11             RH
3           Site1 SQL DB PROD        Server12             PDM
4           Site2 SQL DB PROD        Server21             SP
5           Site2 SQL DB Test        Server21             PDM
```

Table: Backups

```
ID     Server_Name     Backup_Retention     Save_Set
------ --------------- -------------------- ---------------------
1      Server11        3Month               MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER
2      Server11        3Month               MSSQL$ECS
3      Server12        3Month               ALL
4      Server22        3Month               ALL
```

I got close with:

```
SELECT AllNames.Server_Name
      ,CMS.Name
      ,CMS.Responsible
      ,DB.Instance_Name
      ,DB.Name
      ,DB.Company_Code
      ,B.Backup_Retention
      ,B.Save_Set
FROM (SELECT Server_Name FROM CMS
    UNION
    SELECT Server_Name FROM DB
    UNION
    SELECT Server_Name FROM Backups) AllNames
LEFT JOIN DB ON AllNames.Server_Name = DB.Server_Name
FULL JOIN Backups B ON AllNames.Server_Name = B.Server_Name
                                  AND ((B.Save_Set LIKE '%' + DB.Instance_Name OR DB.Instance_Name IS NULL) OR B.Save_Set LIKE 'ALL')
FULL JOIN CMS ON AllNames.Server_Name = CMS.Server_Name
                                 AND CMS.Name LIKE '%' + DB.Name
ORDER BY AllNames.Server_Name ASC
```

Returns:

```
Server_Name   Name                Responsible   Instance_Name   Name    Company_Code   Backup_Retention   Save_Set
------------- ------------------- ------------- --------------- ------- -------------- ------------------ -------------------
NULL          NULL                NULL          NULL            NULL    NULL           3Month             MSSQL$ECS
NULL          Site2 SQL DB Test   PDM           NULL            NULL    NULL           NULL               NULL
Server11      Site1 SQL DB PUB    PDM           MSSQLSERVER     PUB     14             3Month             MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER
Server11      Site1 SQL DB Test   RH            MSSQLSERVER     Test    10             3Month             MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER
Server11      NULL                NULL          MSSQLSERVER     fasys   14             3Month             MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER
Server12      Site1 SQL DB PROD   PDM           MSSQLSERVER     PROD    14             3Month             ALL
Server21      Site2 SQL DB PROD   SP            MSSQLSERVER     PROD    24             NULL               NULL
Server22      NULL                NULL          NULL            NULL    NULL           3Month             ALL
```

What I would like to see (Don't worry about column headers):

```
Server_Name   CMS.Name            CMS.Responsible  DB.Instance_Name  DB.Name  DB.Company_Code  Backups.Backup_Retention  Backups.Save_Set
------------  ------------------  ---------------- ----------------- -------- ---------------- ------------------------- -----------------
Server11      Site1 SQL DB PUB    PDM              MSSQLSERVER       PUB      14               3Month                    MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER
Server11      Site1 SQL DB Test   RH               MSSQLSERVER       Test     10               3Month                    MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER
Server11      NULL                NULL             MSSQLSERVER       fasys    14               3Month                    MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER
Server11      NULL                NULL             NULL              NULL     NULL             3Month                    MSSQL$ECS
Server12      Site1 SQL DB PROD   PDM              MSSQLSERVER       PROD     14               3Month                    ALL
Server21      Site2 SQL DB PROD   SP               MSSQLSERVER       PROD     24               NULL                      NULL
Server21      Site2 SQL DB Test   PDM              NULL              NULL     NULL             NULL                      NULL
Server22      NULL                NULL             NULL              NULL     NULL             3Month                    ALL
```

Create/Populate:

```
CREATE TABLE CMS(
   ID int  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
   Name nvarchar(60)  NOT NULL,
   Server_Name nvarchar(20)  NOT NULL,
   Responsible nvarchar(20)  NULL
   CONSTRAINT CMS_DB_Audit_pk PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE DB(
   ID int  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
   Server_Name nvarchar(20)  NOT NULL,
   Instance_Name nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
   Name nvarchar(60)  NOT NULL,
   Company_Code nvarchar(20)  NULL
   CONSTRAINT DB_pk PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Backups (
   ID int  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
   Server_Name nvarchar(30)  NOT NULL,
   Backup_Retention nvarchar(20)  NOT NULL,
   Save_Set nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT Backups_pk PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
);

INSERT INTO CMS
VALUES 
('Site1 SQL DB PUB','Server11','PDM'),
('Site1 SQL DB Test','Server11','RH'),
('Site1 SQL DB PROD','Server12','PDM'),
('Site2 SQL DB PROD','Server21','SP'),
('Site2 SQL DB Test','Server21','PDM');

INSERT INTO DB
VALUES 
('Server11','MSSQLSERVER','PUB',14),
('Server11','MSSQLSERVER','Test',10),
('Server11','MSSQLSERVER','fasys',14),
('Server12','MSSQLSERVER','PROD',14),
('Server21','MSSQLSERVER','PROD',24);

INSERT INTO Backups
VALUES 
('Server11','3Month','MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER'),
('Server11','3Month','MSSQL$ECS'),
('Server12','3Month','ALL'),
('Server22','3Month','ALL');
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, this is a **great question**! You provide everything a good question needs, thx for that and +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
SELECT coalesce(DB.Server_Name, b.Server_Name, CMS.Server_Name) Server_Name
      ,CMS.Name
      ,CMS.Responsible
      ,DB.Instance_Name
      ,DB.Name
      ,DB.Company_Code
      ,B.Backup_Retention
      ,B.Save_Set
FROM #DB DB --ON AllNames.Server_Name = DB.Server_Name
FULL JOIN #Backups B ON DB.Server_Name = B.Server_Name
                                  AND ((B.Save_Set LIKE '%' + DB.Instance_Name /*OR DB.Instance_Name IS NULL*/) OR B.Save_Set LIKE 'ALL')
FULL JOIN #CMS CMS ON DB.Server_Name = CMS.Server_Name
                                 AND CMS.Name LIKE '%' + DB.Name
ORDER BY coalesce(DB.Server_Name, b.Server_Name, CMS.Server_Name) ASC
```

It'll give result as

```
Server_Name Name    Responsible Instance_Name   Name    Company_Code    Backup_Retention    Save_Set
Server11    Site1 SQL DB PUB    PDM MSSQLSERVER PUB 14  3Month  MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER
Server11    Site1 SQL DB Test   RH  MSSQLSERVER Test    10  3Month  MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER
Server11    NULL    NULL    MSSQLSERVER fasys   14  3Month  MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER
Server11    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3Month  MSSQL$ECS
Server12    Site1 SQL DB PROD   PDM MSSQLSERVER PROD    14  3Month  ALL
Server21    Site2 SQL DB PROD   SP  MSSQLSERVER PROD    24  NULL    NULL
Server21    Site2 SQL DB Test   PDM NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Server22    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3Month  ALL
```

Comment: Both solutions work perfectly but this solution allowed me to simplify a few other things in my script and was a bit more straight forward. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close:

Try this:

```
WITH AllServers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Server_Name FROM DB 
    UNION SELECT Server_Name FROM CMS
    UNION SELECT Server_Name FROM Backups
)
SELECT COALESCE(AllServers.Server_Name,DB.Server_Name,CMS.Server_Name,Backups.Server_Name) AS Server_Name
      ,CMS.Name AS CMS_Name
      ,CMS.Responsible AS CMS_Responsible
      ,DB.Instance_Name AS DB_InstanceName
      ,DB.Name AS [DB_Name]
      ,DB.Company_Code AS DB_CompanyCode
      ,Backups.Backup_Retention
      ,Backups.Save_Set
FROM AllServers
FULL OUTER JOIN DB ON AllServers.Server_Name=DB.Server_Name 
FULL OUTER JOIN Backups ON AllServers.Server_Name=Backups.Server_Name AND (Backups.Save_Set LIKE '%' + DB.Instance_Name OR Backups.Save_Set='ALL')
FULL OUTER JOIN CMS ON AllServers.Server_Name=CMS.Server_Name AND CMS.Name LIKE '%' + DB.Name
ORDER BY COALESCE(AllServers.Server_Name,DB.Server_Name,CMS.Server_Name,Backups.Server_Name)
```

### UPDATE: Tried to find the differences...

I think, your solution is perfect, if you just use my `COALESCE(AllNames.Server_Name,DB.Server_Name,CMS.Server_Name,B.Server_Name)` in your first line and as `ORDER BY`...